# Conceptual side cannot be mapped to object side?

Tags: entity-framework

I use the Entity Framework with Db-First approach. I used to have a table called Ranking that I mapped to an abstract base class with a few inherited concrete classes. Now I recently removed all the inheritance and choose to just use one concrete class called Ranking.

But since I changed it back I get the following runtime Exception:

*Type 'DbModel.Ranking' in conceptual side  cannot be mapped to type 'My.Application.Models.Ranking' on the object side.  Both the types must be abstract or both must be concrete types.*

In my code generation I have set Abstract to false, but I don't know how to change this on the *conceptual* side.

I even tried deleting the Ranking table from my table designer, and then update it again from the database. This didn't help either.

Anyone an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. There was a partial class defined where I forgot to remove the abstract modifier.

So the generated partial class didn't had the abstract modifier anymore, but the other partial still had.

Pretty stupid after all, but hopefully this prevents some other people wasting half an hour.